# syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wonder what's wrong with this code:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['add-to-cart'] ) ) && $matched_id = (int) $_POST['add-to-cart'] ) {            
      $url = 'https://website.com/cart/?add-to-cart=363053'; 
    }
```

It returned a syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND)

Comment: if ( isset( $_POST['add-to-cart'] )  && $matched_id = (int) $_POST['add-to-cart'] ) {            
      $url = 'https://website.com/cart/?add-to-cart=363053'; 
    }

You had too many closing brackets -> two before the && operand, which is closing the if statement too early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some brackets...

Try adding brackets  like :

```
if ( (isset( $_POST['add-to-cart'])) && ($matched_id = (int) $_POST['add-to-cart']) ) {            
  $url = 'https://website.com/cart/?add-to-cart=363053'; 
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Or removing some brackets like :

```
if ( isset( $_POST['add-to-cart'] )  && $matched_id = (int) $_POST['add-to-cart'] ) {            
  $url = 'https://website.com/cart/?add-to-cart=363053'; 
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Remove following part from example I have given when issue fixed...

```
else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if ( isset( $_POST['add-to-cart'] )  && $matched_id = (int) $_POST['add-to-cart'] ) {             $url = 'https://website.com/cart/?add-to-cart=363053';  }`
I think that you have to remove the bracket.